# Dynamic PHP Variable as reference to an array key?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, dynamic, key

So forgive me for any potential stupidity, but I'm trying to reference an array key with the reference itself being a dynamic PHP variable like ${"hello".$hello[0]}.

Here's the code:

```
${"day1".$employeeids[$x]."starttimes"} = $day1starttimesj[${"day1".$employeeids[$x]."key"}]
```

It's telling me there is a syntax error where the $ sign @ [${"day1".$employeeids[$x]."key"}] shouldn't be there.

I would appreciate some englightment as to where I'm going wrong. The $x is simply for a loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this:

```
${"day1".$employeeids[$x]."starttimes"} = $day1starttimesj["day1".$employeeids[$x]."key"]
```

Because the variable `${"day1".$employeeids[$x]."starttimes"}` is assigned on the left but is refered as a dynamic key on the right side. It's pretty much like:

```
$x = $day1starttimesj[$x];
```

which will be failed for sure.